# Why is Rails sharing code between user sessions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When a user tries to sign into our Rails app, I contact a 3rd party ICAM server that returns some information about the user if he exists in the ICAM server.  I get a hash back with the user name, email, etc...  (Our environment is configured in a way that the ICAM server can detect the identify of the person who is attempting to sign in based on their workstation credentials).

We do all of this work in a custom gem.  During the login process, I try to cache the info the ICAM sever returns so I don't have to talk to the ICAM server again.  Naively, I had some code that basically did:

```
module Foo
  def self.store_icam_data(data)
    @icam_data = data
  end

  def self.icam_data
    @icam_data || {}
  end
end
```

I just discovered a problem when two users log into the system.  When User A logs in, `@icam_data` is set with his info.  When User B logs in, `@icam_data` is set with his info.  The next time User A makes a request, `@icam_data` has  by User B's info inside it instead of User A's!

I wasn't expecting the variable inside this module to be shared between threads/sessions like it is.  It effectively makes all current users of the system become the last user who signs in... a pretty gnarly bug.

Can someone explain why the this @icam_data variable is getting shared across sessions? I was expecting the data/code to be more isolated than it apparently is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only two ways you can share data between requests: your database (RDBMS, Redis, etc.) and `session` object (inside of controllers). Any other data which change and survive end of request is side-effect which should be avoided.

Your class variables are saved into memory (RAM) region which belong to particular app server process (e.g. Unicorn worker process). And single process naturally serve many requests, because it's inefficient to kill and restart Rails on each request.

So it's not "Rails sharing code", it's web application server shares its memory region amongst all requests which it serves.

If you want to bind small amount of data to current user, use session:

```
# save
session[:icam_data] = MyICAMModule.get_icam_data

# retain
MyICAMModule.set_icam_data(session[:icam_data])
```

More info on `session` is available in [Action Controller Overview](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session).

If you have large amount of data – use database.